# Error in TEXT field (PostgreSQL) - NHibernate can't read it

Tags: c#, postgresql, nhibernate, blob

I have this entity:

```
public class Product
{
    public virtual long ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductCategory Category { get; set; }
    public virtual byte[] Image { get; set; }
    public virtual string IsAvaliableToSell { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime InsertDate { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }
}
```

With this Map class:

```
public ProductMapping()
{
    [...]
    Map(model => model.Image, "fldProductImage")
        .Insert()
        .Update()
        .Nullable()
        .CustomType("Text");
    [...]
 }
```

When I try to retrieve my products added into database, I got an error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Byte []'.

I think it's in my Image property. Does anyone know what's happening?

Comment: Why do you use `byte[]` for storing a `Text` type? Don't have a lot of experience with PostgreSQL but that seems weird to me.

Comment: Your `Image` is being stored in a `text` column in the database? Why note use `bytea` for binary data?

Comment: Thanks, @muistooshort, bytea type solved my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likely explanation for the *cause* of this is that the `text` type has a couple of limitations and requirements not shared by `bytea`:

- `text` cannot store null bytes because the system uses null-terminated strings; if you submit the byte string `abcd\x00efgh` (where `\x00` is a null byte) the DB will store `abcd`.
- `text` requires data to be valid in the text encoding of the client. When sent from client to server the data is interpreted as being in the client_encoding and converted into the server's text encoding if required. If no conversion is required it is still validated.

So, if you send a bunch of bytes jammed into a text string you'll get truncated mangled gibberish. If you have clients using different encodings you'll probably also get errors fetching the data because of encoding conversion problems.

`bytea` doesn't care what the encoding of the data is, since it's just raw bytes to the server. No conversion is performed. Because it's sent in an escaped form it can contain null bytes. You should always store binary data as `bytea` or use a large object (see the `lo` extension). The only other alternative is to store it converted into some text-safe representation like `base64` but this is very rarely desirable over a `bytea` field.

Answer (score 1):

Changing ***TEXT*** field type to ***BYTEA*** type solved my problem.